# Wordpress update_user_meta not working

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

** SOLVED ** 
I had failed to require Wordpress in the form processor. Adding this line at the top fixed it (always the simplest thing, right!?):
`require_once( explode( "wp-content" , __FILE__ )[0] . "wp-load.php" );`

I've created a custom front-end profile for a client's site, and I'm adding a way for other users to favorite that profile. (Please don't suggest anything like BuddyPress or another plugin -- I've tried about a dozen, and none of them have all of the capabilities I need. Thanks.) :)

Anyway.... here is the overview. I hope it's clear. Let's say that USER 1 is viewing the profile of USER 10.

- In the database, user 1 has a field called favorite_10 which can be set to "yes" or "no" (or null)
- When someone clicks the "Favorite" button in another user's profile, it will run a simple script to change the value from "yes" to "no" or vice-versa

That's it. I think it's a pretty good solution, but the form processing script is breaking at the `update_user_meta` line.

Here we go.

```
foreach($sitterlist as $sitteritem) {
    $code = 'favorite_'.(esc_html($sitteritem->ID));
    $key = esc_html($sitteritem->ID);
    $favorite[$key] = get_the_author_meta( $code, $currentuser);
}

$is_favorite=null;

if ($favorite[$usertosearch]=='yes') {
    $is_favorite = true;
} else {
    $is_favorite = false;
}

?>

<form method="post" action="updatefavorite.php">    
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $usertosearch; ?>" name="usertosearch" id="usertosearch">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $currentuser; ?>" name="currentuser" id="currentuser">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $is_favorite; ?>" name="is_favorite" id="is_favorite">

    <button type="submit" id="favoritebutton" name="favoritebutton"><span>Favorite</span></button>

</form>
```

And here is `updatefavorite.php`

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['favoritebutton'])) {
    $currentuserid = $_POST['currentuser'];
    $currentprofileid = $_POST['usertosearch'];
    $currentfavorite = $_POST['is_favorite'];
    $code = 'favorite_'.$currentprofileid;

    if ($currentfavorite) {
        $currentfavorite = 'no';
    } else {
        $currentfavorite = 'yes';
    }

    update_user_meta($currentuserid,$code,$currentfavorite);
}   

header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

?>
```

After a lot of testing and debugging, I've figured out that it's breaking at `update_user_meta` ... but I don't know why.

Thank you!

Comment: just a remark, some people typed out quite a bit of code to solve the issues you described and you haven't recognised their effort with upvotes/ accepting answers. As to this question you have a mistake in your html, you have a name attribute with a space and no space in your php

Comment: Thanks. I haven't found these posts, and I've searched a lot -- and read probably a dozen -- but I'll continue looking. Thanks for catching that type-o. I don't think it's the issue, although I'll fix it (in my debugging, I've called the script successfully and gotten through every part of the script until update_user_meta, so I am pretty confident that's where the issue is).

UPDATE: That type-o actually isn't in my code. Only in the post.

Comment: have you loaded wordpress in your custom file?

Comment: OHMIGOSH!! It's always something so obvious. Thank you. I added this line `require_once( explode( "wp-content" , __FILE__ )[0] . "wp-load.php" );` and it's perfect. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

** SOLVED ** I had failed to require Wordpress in the form processor. Adding this line at the top fixed it (always the simplest thing, right!?): `require_once( explode( "wp-content" , __FILE__ )[0] . "wp-load.php" );`